# probability of the sum of Bernoulli random values in an interval

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a sequence 1000 iid random variables distributed Bernoulli(1/2).
The central limit theorem says that the probability that X_1+.....+X_1000 lies in the interval (29500,30000) is almost 1? How can I simulate this with Mathematica and represent with a plot?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
distr[n_Integer?Positive] := distr[n] = 
   Module[
       {x, v}, 
       v = Array[x, n];
       TransformedDistribution[Total[v], Thread[v \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1/2]]]
   ]

Probability[x <= 30000, x \[Distributed] distr[1000]]
```

Comment: The sum of `n` independent Bernoulli(1/2) random variables is a binomial random variable with parameters `n` and `1/2`.  So either you can perform simulations with a binomial random variable or exactly calculate the probability of being in that interval using the `CDF` function.  Either would greatly simplify things.  (But if the objective is to learn about `Thread`, that won't help.)

Comment: Shouldn't you have each variable distributed according to `BernoulliDistribution[1/2]`, rather than `BernoulliDistribution[n]`? `n` is the number of variables you are considering; it should not influence each variable's distribution, at least according to my reading of your problem. If you do make that change within `distr`, then your code returns $1$ as you expected. Symbolically, you will also see that `distr[1000]` returns `BinomialDistribution[1000, 1/2]`, as @JimBaldwin mentioned.

Comment: How can the sum of 1000 random variables, each of which is either 0 or 1, possibly exceed 1000? Never mind 29500?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question arsis due to a mistake in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand this correctly. The specification and expectation of sum appear inconsistent. In the following 59500 `BernoulliDistribution[1/2]`<->`BinomialDistribution[59500,1/2]` is close to desired interval:

In the following superimposition of normal approximation is also shown:

```
 bd = BinomialDistribution[59500, 1/2];
Show[Histogram[RandomVariate[bd, 1000], Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[29750, Sqrt[59500/4]], x], {x, 29500, 
   30000}, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]]]
NProbability[29500 < x < 30000, x \[Distributed] bd]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Checking the quality of a Normal-Approximation**

*Note: Your question does not make much sense in the present form, but I am making a slightly different interpretation here than ubpdqn.*

Correcting the error in your code (`BernoulliDistribution[1/2]` instead of `BernoulliDistribution[n]`) will give the result, that the sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli-distributed random vars follows a *Binomial-distribution*:

```
distr[ 1000 ]
```

> BinomialDistribution[ 1000, 1/2 ]

If we are to approximate this distribution by a Gaussian, we must find the parameters for the normal distribution (either by using a sample or by using the PDF of the BinomialDistribution ):

```
mean = Expectation[ x, x \[Distributed] distr[1000] ]
```

> 500

```
sigma = Sqrt @ Expectation[ (x - mean)^2, x \[Distributed] distr[1000] ]
(* we might have used `StandardDeviation`directly, but for the fun of it... *)
```

> $5\sqrt{10}$

We can now check how well this fits empirical trials of size 1000, by repeatedly plotting the (resulting) `SmoothKernelDistribution`:

```
approxDist = NormalDistribution[ mean, sigma ];    

Animate[
    Panel @ Plot[ Evaluate @ {
        PDF[ SmoothKernelDistribution @ RandomVariate[
               distr[1000], 1000 + 0*k]
             ], \[FormalX] 
        ] ,
        PDF[ approxDist , \[FormalX] ]
        },
        { \[FormalX], 400, 600}, (* just showing `where the music plays` *)
        PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.030}},
        Filliing -> Axis,
        PlotLegends -> { "Empirical Distribution", "NormalDistribution" }
    ],
    {k, 0, 100, 1}
]
```

[image: Animated Experiments]

Of course, we could have used

```
approxDist = TruncatedDistribution[ {0, 1000}, distr[1000] ]
```

to account for the fact, that the sum of Bernoulli-distributed random vars will be within the interval [0,1000] - but comparing the distributions will show no great difference.